# JButton in the class and actionlistener on the main

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am new to Java Programming. I would like to create `JButton` inside the class and create `ActionListener` in the main by passing button arguments. But it throws an error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field newBtn
```

My code is as below.

```
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;    
public class TestBtn { 

TestBtn() {
}

public void myBtn(JButton mybtn){   
    JFrame f=new JFrame("My Example");   

    mybtn =new JButton("Click Here");  
    mybtn.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  

    f.add(mybtn);  
    f.setSize(400,400);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);   
} 
}
```

// My Main Program

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;  
public class TestBtnMain {
    JButton newBtn; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestBtn btn = new TestBtn();
    btn.myBtn(newBtn);

    newBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
            System.out.println("Success");
            }  
        });
}
}
```

Comment: just don't do it like that... very bad programming style. `public class TestBtnMain {
    JButton newBtn; ` should be `public class TestBtnMain {
    static JButton newBtn; `

Comment: *"I would like to create `JButton` inside the class and create `ActionListener` in the main by passing button arguments."* Why? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) *"I am new to Java Programming."* Then you probably should avoid GUI programming for a while. It is an advanced topic. Wehn you get back to GUI programming, `f.setLayout(null);` this is one of the things you should **never** do. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to ..

Comment: .. pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: You are really getting things in the wrong place. It is absolutely pointless to create an action listener in your main to pass it around this way. Instead: have a class that extends JFrame; and create your button in there; and simply directly add a listener in that place. Collect experience, and then, when looking into larger examples, learn how to further separate your classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike to C++ Java has no possibility for transfer of parameters by reference. So I would change your code as following:

```
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;    
public class TestBtn { 

    TestBtn() {

    }
    public JButton myBtn(){   

        JFrame f=new JFrame("My Example");   

        JButton mybtn =new JButton("Click Here");  
        mybtn.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  

        f.add(mybtn);  
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);   
        return mybtn;
    } 

}
```

Main class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;  
public class TestBtnMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestBtn btn = new TestBtn();
        JButton newBtn = btn.myBtn();

        newBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
                System.out.println("Success");
            }  
        });


    }
}
```

And, as already mentioned by Andrew Thompson, you should use a layout manager to make your UI working with the different platforms/screen resolutions

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `newBtn` without using any object. It is an instance variable and hence needs an object to be accessed.

This statement should be changed

```
btn.myBtn(newBtn);
```

Use an instance of the class `TestBtnMain` to access `newBtn`

or you can make `newBtn` static.

```
static JButton newBtn;
```

Comment: Now the errors have gone. But actionlistener is not working

Comment: add the actionListener in the `myBtn` method

Answer (score 0):

Your TestBtn class should be :

```
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestBtn { 
  private JFrame f;
  private JButton mybtn;

TestBtn() {
       f=new JFrame("My Example");
       mybtn =new JButton("Click Here"); 
}

public void myBtn(){   

    mybtn.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  
    mybtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
           System.out.println("Success");
        }  
    });

    f.add(mybtn);  
    f.setSize(400,400);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);   
  } 
}
```

And You main function :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;  

public class TestBtnMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestBtn btn = new TestBtn();
      btn.myBtn();
  }
}
```